# Resources for pentesting cloud based services/web-apps?

Tags: penetration-test, cloud-computing

I want to know about some of the good resources for pen-testing cloud based services or web-apps (such as AWS). I googled for it but there are really few good resources out there. For example, I liked this article by SANS: http://pen-testing.sans.org/blog/2012/07/05/pen-testing-in-the-cloud

Apart from this, does anyone have good resources for pen-testing cloud based services/web-apps? It would also be great if someone could share their experience of performing a pen-test on service/web-app hosted on the cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this article at: 
cryptome.org/2013/07/cloud-pentest.pdf

also this video might be helpful though it is from a less technical viewpoint: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXiv8VFOHcA

lastly I would recommend looking at this article as it might give you some good ideas:
www.mecs-press.org/ijcnis/ijcnis-v3-n3/IJCNIS-V3-N3-1.pdf

pen-testing cloud based services is still a fairly new subject so naturally there are limited resources :)